# Transform async.parallel to async.auto

Tags: node.js, express, async.js

I have an async.parallel with 2 functions, and now I need to transform to async.auto or async.waterfall because I need to pass a value from the first function to the second.

Both functions return an array. In the second function the param timeAdjust will has the value from array1.timeAdjust

Can anyone help me?

The code:

```
router.get('/:machineID', function(req, res, next) {
    var machineID = req.params.machineID;

    async.parallel({
        one: function(callback){
            auxPrinters.function1(machineID, 'ent', function(array1){
                callback(null, array1);
            });
        },
        two: function(callback){
            auxPrinters.function2(machineID, 'ent', timeAdjust, function(array2){
                callback(null, array2);
            });
        },      
    },
    function(err, results){  //results.one=array1 & results.two=array2
        if(err) {console.log("****** ERROR:"); console.log(err);}
        else{
            console.dir(results);
            res.render('jobs', {title: 'Job Info', results});
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is your answer, but before that it is weird for me that you want to write array1.timeAdjust if array is an array, so I will just believe that array1 is an object

```
router.get('/:machineID', function(req, res, next) {
    var machineID = req.params.machineID;

    async.waterfall([
        function(callback){
            auxPrinters.function1(machineID, 'ent', function(array1){
                callback(null, array1);
            });
        },
        function(array1, callback){
            var result = {}
            result.one = array1
            timeAdjust = array1.timeAdjust
            auxPrinters.function2(machineID, 'ent', timeAdjust, function(array2){
                result.two = array1
                callback(null, result);
            });
        },      
    ],
    function(err, results){  //results.one=array1 & results.two=array2
        if(err) {console.log("****** ERROR:"); console.log(err);}
        else{
            console.dir(results);
            res.render('jobs', {title: 'Job Info', results});
        }
    });
});
```

as you can see I didn't pass array.timeAdjust but the full array1 since you want array1 and array2 at the final callback

Comment: Can you mark the answer as correct if it solves your problem please ? :D

Comment: I recieve this error:

Error: First argument to waterfall must be an array of functions

Comment: No, no, my fault! I didn't see the [ ]!!

But I need the results has both arrays! Array1 and array2.

Answer (score 0):

**Final Solution:**

```
async.waterfall([
        function(callback){
            console.log("****** ASYNC JOBS 1");
            auxPrinters.function1(machineID, 'ent', function(array1){
                callback(null, array1);
            });
        },
        function(array1, callback){
            console.log("****** ASYNC JOBS 2");
            auxPrinters.function2(machineID, 'ent', array1, function(array2){
                callback(null, array1, array2);
            });
        },      
    ],
    function(err, array1, array2){
        if(err) {console.log("****** ERROR ASYNC:"); console.log(err);}
        else{
            res.render('jobs', {title: 'Job Info', array1, array2});
        }
    });
```